# Any tools for SQLSERVER backups/snapshots?

Tags: java, sql-server, database-backups, snapshot

I have 3 related questions.

1) I need to have a snapshot of an SQLSERVER database. According to documentation, I can use

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO DISK ...
```

But it creates the backup file in database server itself. Is there a way to get it created in client machine?

2) There is another option to `Generate Scripts` in Management Studio. Is there a way to call this programmatically (JDBC)? [Note:I'm using java]

3) Are there any tools (like mysqldump in MySQL) which I can use to get a snapshot of a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions

> 1. backup to client machine.

This term is actually "[How to Backup SQL Databases to a Network Share](http://www.howtogeek.com/51788/how-to-backup-sql-databases-to-a-network-share/)". Beware that there are some caveats with this approach.

> 2. Generate Scripts

This can be used from .NET languages via [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms162169.aspx).

> 3. Other tools

Other third party tools exists like [Red Gate Sql Server Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/)

Comment: Thanks for `1` and `3`. Regarding `2`: I'm using Java. Is there a way to do this via JDBC driver?

Comment: It may be possible to do so. But easy way would be using .NET platform.

Comment: My application is java.

Comment: Alas, Sql Server-.NET integration is better than Sql Server-java integration.

Comment: Yes, but I have no option as this is just a part of a large java project.